# crashing my application due to NSAUTORELEASENOPOOL

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am using navigation controller and my first view contains tableof data of chapters type and 
then when user selects any one of those it goes to next view of topics type and when user selects any one of these it should show some table of data consists section headers and ruler items...
application getting crashing when i selects topics so it is not  displaying 3rd view of sections...
the console is showing that some error log 
i am attatching this here..

in second view didselect row method i am having problem,when i change variable here its effecting o/p

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if(TviewController == nil)
    TviewController = [[TopicRulesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopicRulesViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    Topic *bTopic = [bchapter.topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
WHEN I CHANGED THIS VARIABLE BCHAPTER.TOPICS ITS GIVING EMPTY VIEW...   
        TviewController.aTopic = bTopic;
    TVIEWCONTROLLER IS THE THIRD VIEW CONTROLLER ....



    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TviewController animated:YES];
}
```

---

```
[Session started at 2010-07-20 07:36:03 -0700.]
2010-07-20 07:36:06.740 UpWrite[69558:207] No Errors
2010-07-20 07:36:09.850 UpWrite[69558:207] No Errors
2010-07-20 07:36:11.393 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b675d0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x5f29 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.396 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b5a160 of class WebEditorUndoTarget autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317e9ee 0x317dd8d 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.397 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3910400 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x317ea5c 0x317ddf3 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.400 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3953fc0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1e0d0 0x1d159 0x1d07a 0x317ddf3 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.402 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b25240 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x2559f16 0x2559e08 0x317f9e2 0x317f548 0x25d0c1a 0x25d037a 0x25d02a5 0x25d020e 0x25cfa25 0x317ecc7 0x317eb36 0x317de71 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.403 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b45a70 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x25adf33 0x2be69c8 0x25adebb 0x25c2ec8 0x25c2d64 0x25c298b 0x25c290e 0x25d41d8 0x25cfa5c 0x317ecc7 0x317eb36 0x317de71 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.408 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208a44 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318204c 0x31815a5 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.409 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208ae4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x318208c 0x31815d1 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.410 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208a94 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x31820cc 0x3181655 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.411 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208aa4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x318210c 0x3181676 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.412 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208a84 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x318214c 0x3181697 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.414 UpWrite[69558:207] load data.............
2010-07-20 07:36:11.414 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208ad4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x318218c 0x31816e0 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.419 UpWrite[69558:207]  view will appear...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.424 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.425 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.425 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.425 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.425 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.425 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.426 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.426 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.426 UpWrite[69558:207] height for row...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.427 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.421 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208b14 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x31821cc 0x3181768 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.427 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.429 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.429 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.429 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.430 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.430 UpWrite[69558:207] cell for row.................
2010-07-20 07:36:11.428 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x396b900 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1e0d0 0x3e18f 0x3e0da 0x318185a 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.436 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x31822dc 0x31818c8 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.437 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318231c 0x31818f1 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.438 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208ac4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x318235c 0x318191a 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.441 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208ab4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x318239c 0x318193b 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.445 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x31823dc 0x318195c 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.446 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318241c 0x3181985 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.504 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318245c 0x31819ae 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.507 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208af4 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x318249c 0x31819d7 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.508 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208b04 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x31824dc 0x3181a5f 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.509 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208b04 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317eaaa 0x318251c 0x3181ae7 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.510 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318255c 0x3181b65 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.511 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x39222a0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x318259c 0x3181b8e 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.512 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318273c 0x31826f2 0x3181c09 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.513 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x3182819 0x3181c32 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.518 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318285c 0x3181c5b 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.545 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x318289c 0x3181c84 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.546 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208a24 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x1f4ba 0x31828f1 0x3181cad 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.547 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3208a34 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x1f4ba 0x3182981 0x3181cfb 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.562 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x31829bc 0x3181d13 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.568 UpWrite[69558:207] web view load complete...........
2010-07-20 07:36:11.569 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x39bc350 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x3182a41 0x31829fc 0x3181d40 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.571 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3998c20 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x3182abc 0x3181d5b 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.572 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x39a2400 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x3182a41 0x3182afc 0x3181d83 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.574 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x3182b3c 0x3181dd4 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.577 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c608 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x3182b7c 0x3181dfd 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.578 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c8c600 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x317d871 0x317d829 0x3182bbc 0x3181e26 0x317df98 0x317db57 0x317da7c 0x317da06 0x407ed6 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.579 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3baaaf0 of class WAKClipView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x25a6577 0x3183035 0x254c1ec 0x254c1bc 0x254c1bc 0x254c1bc 0x254c1bc 0x25a638d 0x400b40 0x407f28 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.580 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3903f60 of class UIDefaultWebViewInteractionDelegate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x400c4a 0x407f28 0x414caf 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.589 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3907a70 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x4004d0 0x40028c 0x414ccd 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.590 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x398db50 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x1bd20fc 0x4004f0 0x40028c 0x414ccd 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.591 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x398db90 of class NSConcreteNotification autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x400520 0x40028c 0x414ccd 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.598 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x39bc350 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x317d958 0x3182a41 0x31905eb 0x31905a3 0x415255 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.603 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x394db40 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1e0d0 0x3e18f 0x3e0da 0x31c3242 0x415295 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.604 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x39519d0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x4152c6 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.605 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b5ffa0 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x2b0783 0x4164c5 0x415310 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.606 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3bdeeb0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x41653b 0x415310 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.607 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3bb8740 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x407587 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.608 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b54830 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x4075c1 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.609 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b9dc90 of class WebBackForwardList autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x3186be1 0x407610 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.610 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3bf8e80 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x4076f4 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.611 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b10890 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x25adf33 0x2be69c8 0x25adebb 0x25c2ec8 0x25c2d64 0x25c298b 0x25c290e 0x25c28db 0x25b2ae4 0x25de5b7 0x3190346 0x31901c4 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.612 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b57c30 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x1bee4b7 0x1bca6c2 0x3187df3 0x25b292a 0x25de5b7 0x3190346 0x31901c4 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.613 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3b53730 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x25adf33 0x31d0114 0x3187e51 0x25c52dd 0x25b298d 0x25de5b7 0x3190346 0x31901c4 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.614 UpWrite[69558:440f] *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3bf8590 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0xbb6bf 0x1ce62 0x1bee4b7 0x1bca6c2 0x3187e80 0x25c52dd 0x25b298d 0x25de5b7 0x3190346 0x31901c4 0x3fff35 0x415333 0x415bed 0x5fb5 0x22f7d 0x22b18 0x91f8f81d 0x91f8f6a2)
2010-07-20 07:36:11.624 UpWrite[69558:440f] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x3b108f0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Comment: Could you show or tell us about the code where this error occurs? There are several things that could cause this, one being `a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread.`

Comment: Most likely you just created an extra thread without creating an autorelease pool for it.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an instance of NSAutoreleasePool, probably because your method is executed on another thread.

Simply create it, and release it at the end of your method:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [ [ NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init ];
/* your code... */
[ pool release ];
```

NSAutoreleasePool are responsible to release the objects on which the '`autorelease`' message is send.
Note that when using convenience constructors, objects are autoreleased. So if you have no pool, the objects won't be released.

A pool exists on the main thread, but for methods executing on other threads, it needs to be created manually.

Note that you can have more than one instance of NSAutoreleasePool in the same thread. It's sometimes useful to avoid long retain cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You crash because you auto-release some objects, with no [auto-release pool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in place.
An auto-release pool is an object that holds the objects that are sent an *autorelease* message, and take care of releasing them when it receive the drain message.
Cocoa expects to always have an autorelease pool available.

Why you have no auto-release pool is hard to say without more context.

When your app start, in main.m, an auto-release pool is created. Maybe you modified this code?
Or you created a new thread, but didn't created an auto-release pool.

Anyway, here is how to create one:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Your code goes here
[pool release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is, like the other community members here already mentioned, that you are running a thread without an `NSAutoreleasePool` allocated or "wrapping it". But the main issue i believe you have is, that you try to draw something on the screen from another Thread than the one the User Interface was allocated.

Never call any messages that manipulate some UI elements from a different Thread. The reason is that Graphic Buffer and other appropriate memory is not threadsafe. Doing so leads to undefined behavior, an assertion failure or just crashes. When you need to update any UI Elements from another Thread put your messages in the appropriate runloop by calling

```
[objectToUpdate performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
```

or with whatever synchronizing mechanism you use. The above message puts the message in the queue of the runloop of the main thread. It will be executed when the runloop continues next time, but in the correct thread. The precondition is, for sure, that you initialized your UI Elements in the main tread (which is the case in 99% of all applications). Otherwise you could call the

```
[objectToUpdate performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]
```

message to address any other thread.